# Flex and Twitter data visualization

Tags: php, apache-flex, twitter

Is it possible to run the .json file which is has status data from twitter and run it with flex to create a visualization of the data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is.

Look at the [Twitter API Wiki](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/API-Overview) and watch a [tutorial about this](http://gotoandlearn.com/play?id=99) of Lee Brimelow.